# Reledmac, lineation problem

Tags: reledmac

The problem for which I ask for a solution arises when the conditions of the fifth block of the MWE are met, that is, when it begins with the page. In that case and only in that case, the numbering does not start over from one. I tried to change the font but the problem remains.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
               twoside,
               openright,
               8pt,
               final]
               {memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\AtBeginDocument{\linespread{1}}
\usepackage[]{polyglossia}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  BIBLIOGRAFIA
\usepackage[bibstyle=alphabetic,
        %bibstyle=debug,
        citestyle=alphabetic,
        backref,
        backrefstyle=none,
        backend=bibtex8,
        ]
                     {biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib4.bib}

\usepackage[series={A,B,C,D,E},noledgroup,noend,noquotation,noeledsec]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
\setgoalfraction{.95}
\numberlinetrue
\linenumincrement*{1}

\setlength{\linenumsep}{1.5mm}
                
\firstlinenum*{0}
\setRlineflag{d}
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{75mm} 
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{70mm} 
\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}

\Xlemmaseparator[A]{$\ulrcorner$}
\Xlemmaseparator[B]{$\ulrcorner$}
\Xlemmaseparator[C]{$\ulrcorner$}
\Xlemmaseparator[D]{$\ulrcorner$}
\Xlemmaseparator[E]{$\ulrcorner$}

\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[C]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[D]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[E]{paragraph}

\Xnotefontsize[A]{\footnotesize}
\Xnotefontsize[B]{\footnotesize}
\Xnotefontsize[C]{\footnotesize}
\Xnotefontsize[D]{\footnotesize}
\Xnotefontsize[E]{\footnotesize}

\Xlemmadisablefontselection[A]
\Xlemmadisablefontselection[B]
\Xlemmadisablefontselection[C]
\Xlemmadisablefontselection[D]
\Xlemmadisablefontselection[E]
    


    \Xlemmafont[A]{\itshape\normalsize}
    \Xlemmafont[B]{\itshape\normalsize}
    \Xlemmafont[C]{\itshape\normalsize}
    \Xlemmafont[D]{\itshape\normalsize}
    \Xlemmafont[E]{\itshape\normalsize}
    
\setlength{\ledrsnotesep}{6mm}
\setlength{\ledlsnotesep}{6mm}

\setlength{\ledlsnotewidth}{70pt}
\setlength{\ledrsnotewidth}{70pt}

\fnpos{%
{A}{critical},%
{B}{critical},%
{C}{critical},%
{D}{critical},%
{E}{critical},%
{A}{familiar},%
{B}{familiar},%
{C}{familiar},%
{D}{familiar},%
{E}{familiar}%
}

\Xtxtbeforenotes[A]{M $\cdot$ }  %%%% note del manoscritto
\Xtxtbeforenotes[B]{T $\cdot$ }  %%%% note della traduzione
\Xtxtbeforenotes[C]{V $\cdot$ }  %%%% varianti del manoscritto
\Xtxtbeforenotes[D]{D $\cdot$ }  %%%% definizioni
\Xtxtbeforenotes[E]{C $\cdot$ }  %%%% concetti principali
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguages{french}
\setotherlanguages{hebrew}
\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}
\setlrmarginsandblock{27mm}{33mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{27mm}{38mm}{*}
\setheaderspaces{*}{8pt}{*}
\setheadfoot{25pt}{25pt}
\checkandfixthelayout

%       \setmainfont{Brill Roman}[Scale=1,Ligatures = {Rare,Common}]    
%       \renewcommand{\numlabfont}{\fontspec{Brill Roman}\tiny}
        \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}[Scale=.79]
        \lineation*{page}
\begin{document}

    \begin{pairs}%
        \begin{Leftside}%
            \beginnumbering%
                \pstart%
\lipsum[1]
                \pend%
            \pausenumbering%
        \end{Leftside}%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%% 1st block 
        \begin{Rightside}%
            \beginnumbering%
                \pstart%
\lipsum[2]
                \pend%
            \pausenumbering%
        \end{Rightside}%
    \end{pairs}%
\Columns%

    \begin{pairs}%
        \begin{Leftside}%
            \resumenumbering%
                \pstart%
\lipsum[3]
                \pend%
            \pausenumbering%
        \end{Leftside}%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%% 2nd block
        \begin{Rightside}%
            \resumenumbering%
                \pstart%
\lipsum[4]
                \pend%
            \pausenumbering%
        \end{Rightside}%
    \end{pairs}%
\Columns%
    \begin{pairs}%
        \begin{Leftside}%
            \resumenumbering%
                \pstart%
\lipsum[5]
                \pend%
            \pausenumbering%
        \end{Leftside}%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%% 3rd block 
        \begin{Rightside}%
            \resumenumbering%
                \pstart%
\lipsum[6]
                \pend%
            \pausenumbering%
        \end{Rightside}%
    \end{pairs}%
\Columns%
    \begin{pairs}%
        \begin{Leftside}%
            \resumenumbering%
                \pstart%
\lipsum[7]
                \pend%
            \pausenumbering%
        \end{Leftside}%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%% 4th block     
        \begin{Rightside}%
            \resumenumbering%
                \pstart%
\lipsum[8]
                \pend%
            \pausenumbering%
        \end{Rightside}%
    \end{pairs}%
\Columns%
    \begin{pairs}%
        \begin{Leftside}%
            \resumenumbering%
                \pstart%
\lipsum[9]
                \pend%
            \pausenumbering%
        \end{Leftside}%
        %%%%%%%%%%%%% 5th block     
        \begin{Rightside}%
            \resumenumbering%
                \pstart%
\lipsum[10]
                \pend%
            \pausenumbering%
        \end{Rightside}%
    \end{pairs}%
\Columns%
\end{document}
```

Comment: did you try with real text, not lipsum package? If yes, please open an issue on github.

Comment: Yes, I tried and I'll open an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions 2.34.4 of reledmac +  2.24.2 of reledpar, which I will send today on CTAN, fix this bug.